# Entity Framework 6 Self Join not populating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QUESTIONS](
    [QUESTION_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QUESTION_TEXT] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PARENT_QUESTION_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_QUESTIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QUESTION_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QUESTIONS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_QUESTIONS_QUESTIONS] FOREIGN KEY([PARENT_QUESTION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[QUESTIONS] ([QUESTION_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QUESTIONS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_QUESTIONS_QUESTIONS]
GO
```

Basically PARENT_QUESTION_ID is a self join on QUESTION_ID. I'm trying to implement this in EF 6.0 Code First.

In the class I have:

```
[Serializable]
[Table("QUESTIONS")]
public class Question : BaseDomainModel, IQuestion
{
    [Column("QUESTION_ID")]
    public override int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("QUESTION_TEXT")]
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    [Column("PARENT_QUESTION_ID")]
    public int? ParentQuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual IQuestion Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentQuestionId")]
    public virtual List<IQuestion> ChildQuestions { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        ChildQuestions = new List<IQuestion>();
    }
}
```

The code executes but ChildQuestions never populates. For example, if I have this in the database:
[image]

Records 24 and 25 should be populated in ChildQuestions list for Question 26. Instead nothing appears.

Here is the call I make to populate the Question from the Repository:

```
public IQuestion GetById(int id)
{
    IQuestion question = null;

    using (var db = new MainContext())
    {
        question = db.Questions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    }

    return question;
}
```

Here is the context that I'm using:

```
internal class MainContext : DbContext
{
    internal MainContext() : base("name=ACME.Context") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the `ForeignKey` attribute on the wrong property. Instead of being on `ChildQuestions` it should be on `Parent`:

```
[ForeignKey("ParentQuestionId")]
public virtual IQuestion Parent { get; set; }

public virtual List<IQuestion> ChildQuestions { get; set; }
```

Comment: Still comes up with zero results for the ChildQuestions list. Also, Parent is null even though ParentQuestionId is populated when looking at a child record. Do I need to add an include in Linq in the GetById() method?

Comment: Try it as type Question instead of IQuestion, and see if that does it n

Comment: When I look at ChildQuestions in Watch, I see an odd error message for the value: 
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. I had updated it use List<Question>

Comment: That worked for Parent, it is now populated. Not using an Interface breaks my model, I have to use interfaces because of the way my projects are structured, otherwise I'll receive Circular references errors between projects.

Comment: Try using what's mentioned here: http://antix.co.uk/Blog/EF4-Code-First-and-Interface-Property-Types